# Aggregating content from Facebook and WordPress website to a weekly newsletter

Tags: email, wordpress, facebook, marketing, newsletter

I am looking for software that will help me to aggregate posts from my **Facebook** fanpage and WordPress-based **website** to a weekly **newsletter**.

The usual drill is to write a newsletter (old school) to a whole bunch of email adresses. I usually include information from posts I did on Facebook and my WordPress-themed website. I add some lines in between to make it a coherent newsletter to keep my subscribers informed.

You can imagine that this way of compiling a newsletter is rather annoying if you have a lot to cover.

---

**My wish:** 
I would like to use a program that is able to connect to both my Facebook fanpage and my website, fetch posts from the last week (or more) and let me choose what to include in the actual newsletter. Then add some lines in between.

It does not necessarily need to be a native OS application (OS X here); a web app is also fine with me.

---

I googled quite a lot, but I could not find a proper solution. If you are looking for something similar, here is what I've found so far:

- [fanbridge.com social digest creator newsletter](https://www.fanbridge.com/socialdigest/learn_more.php) - It's not for free.
- [Question on WordPress forum: custom email digest/newsletter across categories?](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-question-custom-email-digestnewsletter-across-categories) - It's solely for WordPress.
- [Kidpost](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-facebook-photos-by-email/13737/) - A solution for parents, that want to keep relatives updated with photos of cute children via content from Facebook to E-Mail. Not what I'am looking for.
- [Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) - I am using Mailchimp with another project. It doesn't have an option to include social content.

Comment: I have no personal experience with thes, but investigate [NetVibes](http://www.netvibes.com/en) and [Paper.li](http://paper.li/)

Comment: Thanks for the update! With "free" being a nice-to-have, you might wish to name a budget (a la "free would be nice, but a one-time price of up to USD30 would be acceptable").

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [python](http://python.org) and the libraries [wordpress_json](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wordpress_json) and one of the many facebook API libraries, *[requests-facebook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-facebook) looks promising*, to fetch your information.

Once you have it there are an huge number of possibilities for formatting it for output into a draft newsletter for you to edit and send.

### Pluses

- Free, Open Source & Gratis
- Handle both Facebook & WordPress
- Can output whatever you want
- You learn some python
- If you didn't wish to do the edit step it could post for you.
- Lots of community support
- You will be amazed how little code you need *- take a look at the examples on the library links*.

### Minuses

- You need to learn some python
- You have to do the work of writing and testing the code